# Where can I find Quarkus security-ldap-quickstart?

Tags: security, ldap, quarkus

I was reading the Quarkus Security LDAP guide at https://quarkus.io/guides/security-ldap and I would like to look at the recommended solution.
However, when I try to lookup the address which is given in the article (https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/main/security-ldap-quickstart), I get a 404.
Furthermore, the solution cannot be found in the list of quarkus-quickstarts at https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts.git
What happened to it ? Is it stored somewhere else now ?

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right, it looks like it's missing and I can't find any trace of it in the pending pull requests.

Could you create an issue in our tracker (https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus) so that I can ping the appropriate persons there?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not have an account on GitHub. Can you do it ?